# How to define and add a enum as type

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, ado.net

I am working on [custom data provider](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2010/01/07/data-service-providers-getting-started.aspx) using ADO .NET Entity Framework.

In the CreateMetaData function, I need to add primitive and complex properties in the ResourceType.

I believe Enum should be added as the complex data type.

If yes, how can I add this? Any pointer would be a great help.

Thanks,

Ram

Comment: may be you should give more information, in order we can help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/alexj/tip-23-how-to-fake-enums-in-ef-4) Enums are not supported in Entity Framework 4. But it can be achieved using POCO classes.

Answer (score 0):

An enum can be initialized as following:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    FirstEntry,
    SecondEntry,
    ThirdEntry
}
```

You can access it using `MyEnum.FirstEntry`.

The enum can be added to a class as a property, for example:

```
public MyEnum NumberOfEntry { get; set; }
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: @Peter van Kekem : The Enum is already define, I need to expose it in CreateMetadata function.

Comment: I don't see why you cannot just assign the enum in the function... maybe you should add some more information around? For example, the createmetadata function you have until now, how you want to assign the ResourceType, etc.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, But I feel I need to add the enum as complex type and I do not know how to add it.

Comment: Add enum to ResourceType as a ComplexProperty.

Comment: What type or class is the ResourceType?

Comment: Resource type is a class in which I want to add an Enum.

Comment: I've added an example in my answer. Hope this will help you out.

Comment: EF4 does not have support for Enum :(

Comment: Then try to add it as an int by casting it to int.